# How to catch SIGABRT in multithread environment?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I want to create an Units test framwork, but to provide a good reporting I need to catch SIGABRT, SIGSEGV and probably others signals to prevent my process from being killed (And so, to be able to continue the tests processing)...

But I don't know how to do this and so, I need information:

- SIGABRT is a thread direct signal ?
- What happens if I only use the main thread to catch the SIGABRT (or SIGSEGV) signal? Could the thread that called abort return from its call (I hope not) ?

If you have any useful documents, links or tutorial, I'm interested. It's for a C code using pthreads.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to catch SIGABRT, SIGSEGV and probably others signals to prevent my process from being killed

This is an exercise in futility. After `SIGABRT` or `SIGSEGV` is raised, you (in general) *have no idea* about the state of the process -- it may have corrupted heap, stack, global data internal to your test framework, global data internal to the C runtime system, etc. etc. Continuing such process is exceedingly likely to continue crashing at random (correct) places in the code.

The *only* sane way to handle this in a test framework is to `fork` and have the *parent* process handle child error exits, report them and continue running additional tests.

> SIGABRT is a thread direct signal ?

There is no such thing as "direct signal". `SIGABRT` may be sent to the process from outside, or it can be `raise`d inside the process.

> What happens if I only use the main thread to catch the SIGABRT (or SIGSEGV) signal?

`SIGSEGV` and `SIGABRT` (when not sent from outside) is sent to the thread which caused the invalid memory operation (or `raise`d it).

In addition, there is *no way* to "only use main thread" -- `sigaction` is global across all threads (though you can set a thread-specific signal mask).